# Tikz: Copy segment length

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to have a macro which uses the length between to points to calculate another calculate, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,5);
    \coordinate (C) at (7,0);

    % Is this possible?
    % From point C to the direction of point A with the length of
    % from point A to point B
    % \coordinate (D) at ($(C)!(A)!(A)-(B)$);
    % or
    % From point C to the direction of 60 degrees with the length of
    % from point A to point B
    % \coordinate (D) at ($(C)!(60)!(A)-(B)$);

    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,5);
    \coordinate (C) at (7,0);

    % Is this possible?
    % From point C to the direction of point A with the length of
    % from point A to point B
    \path let \p1=($(B)-(A)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in   ($(C)!\n1!(A)$)
    coordinate(D) ($(C)+(60:\n1)$) coordinate (D');
    % or
    % From point C to the direction of 60 degrees with the length of
    % from point A to point B
    % \coordinate (D) at ($(C)!(60)!(A)-(B)$);

    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw[blue,thick] (C) -- (D);
    \draw[red,thick] (C) -- (D');
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with styles:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[towards/.style args={#1 from #2 with length from #3 to #4}{%
insert path={let \p1=($(#3)-(#4)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
($(#2)!\n1!(#1)$)}},into direction/.style args={#1 from #2 with length from #3 to #4}{%
insert path={let \p1=($(#3)-(#4)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
($(#2)+(#1:\n1)$)}}]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,5);
    \coordinate (C) at (7,0);

    % Is this possible?
    % From point C to the direction of point A with the length of
    % from point A to point B
    \path[towards={A from C with length from A to B}] 
    coordinate(D) ;
    % or
    % From point C to the direction of 60 degrees with the length of
    % from point A to point B
    % \coordinate (D) at ($(C)!(60)!(A)-(B)$);
    \path[into direction={60 from C with length from A to B}] 
    coordinate(D') ;

    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw[blue,thick] (C) -- (D);
    \draw[red,thick] (C) -- (D');
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I ask for an extension this beautiful solution (or does it have to be a separate question?) Say I want to go from point C to the direction of 60 degrees relative to line CD (similar to `(A)!1!60:(B)`, etc. with length from x to y. How would I do that?

Comment: @blackened You could do `\tikzset{into rotated direction/.style args={of #1 from #2 by #3 with length from #4 to #5}{%
insert path={let \p1=($(#4)-(#5)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},\p2=($(#1)-(#2)$), 
\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)} in ($(#2)+(\n2+#3:\n1)$)}}}`. and then use it e.g. like `\path[into rotated direction={of B from C by 60 with length from A to B}] 
    coordinate(D'') ;
 \draw[orange,thick] (C) -- (D'');` in the above example. I am not sure, though, if there is a large demand for that, so I hesitate to edit the answer.